# PieCloudDB Database SUM a column base on unique values of another column

Tags: sql, group-by

Suppose I have a table that looks like so:

| ID | Quantity | Record |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 8 | ae8 |
| 111 | 1 | aac |
| 111 | 8 | ae8 |
| 111 | 28 | acg |
| 111 | 9 | bbb |
| 128 | 3 | pie |
| 128 | 3 | pie |

I want to group this by ID then SUM the Quantity but only by the unique Record values.
So that my end result looks like this:

| ID | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | 46 |
| 128 | 3 |

Comment: What if "Quantity" is different for the same "Record" value, which one should be chosen to contribute to the SUM?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using SQL's GROUP BY clause along with SUM and DISTINCT functions to calculate the sum of unique quantities for each ID. Here's the SQL query you can use:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ID, Record, Quantity
    FROM YourTableName
) AS Subquery
GROUP BY ID;
```

Replace **YourTableName** with the actual name of your table. This query first calculates the sum of quantities for each unique combination of ID and Record using a subquery. Then, it groups the results of the subquery by ID to calculate the sum of unique quantities for each ID.

Applying this query to your sample data would yield the desired result.

Comment: It's with assumption we just distinct multiple ID with same record and quantity. If you just want to aggregate only based on ID, you can use select group by with your desire aggregation (max/min/sum/etc)

Answer (score 0):

I offer my solution using row_number partitioning on id and record.

```
WITH DATA AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY ID, RECORD ORDER BY ID)AS RN
 FROM YOUR_TABLE)
SELECT ID, SUM(QUANTITY )AS QTY
FROM DATA
WHERE RN=1
GROUP BY ID;
```

Hope it helps.